# Cannot compile Stroustrup GUI Libraries

Tags: c++

I managed to install `FLTK` properly and it compiles if I use library like this `#include<FL/Fl_Window.H>`, but now I want to compile this libraries attached below through the code provided below also;
libraries link:
`https://github.com/BjarneStroustrup/Programming-_Principles_and_Practice_Using_Cpp`
here are also images, shown with the errors when compiling if I will uncomment `Polygon` it shows different error with this content `Polygon is ambiguous` provided screens below also;

CODE:

```
#include "Simple_window.h" // get access to our window library
#include "Graph.h" // get access to our graphics library facilities
int main()
{
using namespace Graph_lib; // our graphics facilities are in Graph_lib
Point tl {100,100}; // to become top left corner of window
Simple_window win {tl,600,400,"Canvas"}; // make a simple window
Polygon poly; // make a shape (a polygon)
poly.add(Point{300,200}); // add a point
poly.add(Point{350,100}); // add another point
poly.add(Point{400,200}); // add a third point
poly.set_color(Color::red); // adjust properties of poly
win.attach (poly); // connect poly to the window
win.wait_for_button(); // give control to the display engine
}
```

Error When compile code above:

```
 C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\C++\GUI_Train\Libs\Test_output.cpp: In function 'int main()':
    C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\C++\GUI_Train\Libs\Test_output.cpp:8:5: error: reference to 'Polygon' is ambiguous
        8 |     Polygon poly; // make a shape (a polygon)
          |     ^~~~~~~
    In file included from C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\C++\GUI_Train\Libs\GUI.h:11,
                     from C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\C++\GUI_Train\Libs\Simple_window.h:2,
                     from C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\C++\GUI_Train\Libs\Test_output.cpp:1:
    C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\C++\GUI_Train\Libs\Graph.h:248:8: note: candidates are: 'struct Graph_lib::Polygon'
      248 | struct Polygon : Closed_polyline {      // closed sequence of non-intersecting lines
          |        ^~~~~~~
    In file included from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/windows.h:71,
                     from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/FL/Fl_Window.H:26,
                     from C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\C++\GUI_Train\Libs\Window.h:5,
                     from C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\C++\GUI_Train\Libs\GUI.h:10:
    C:/msys64/mingw64/include/wingdi.h:3467:28: note:                 'WINBOOL Polygon(HDC, const POINT*, int)'
     3467 |   WINGDIAPI WINBOOL WINAPI Polygon(HDC hdc,CONST POINT *apt,int cpt);
          |                            ^~~~~~~
    C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\C++\GUI_Train\Libs\Test_output.cpp:9:5: error: 'poly' was not declared in this scope
        9 |     poly.add(Point{300,200}); // add a point
```

When Comment Out the `using namespace Graph_lib`

```
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\C++\GUI_Train\Libs\Test_output.cpp -lfltk -o C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\C++\GUI_Train\Libs\Test_output.exe
C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\C++\GUI_Train\Libs\Test_output.cpp: In function 'int main()':
C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\C++\GUI_Train\Libs\Test_output.cpp:8:5: error: reference to 'Polygon' is ambiguous
    8 |     Polygon poly; // make a shape (a polygon)
      |     ^~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\C++\GUI_Train\Libs\GUI.h:11,
                 from C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\C++\GUI_Train\Libs\Simple_window.h:2,
                 from C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\C++\GUI_Train\Libs\Test_output.cpp:1:
C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\C++\GUI_Train\Libs\Graph.h:248:8: note: candidates are: 'struct Graph_lib::Polygon'
  248 | struct Polygon : Closed_polyline {      // closed sequence of non-intersecting lines
      |        ^~~~~~~
In file included from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/windows.h:71,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/FL/Fl_Window.H:26,
                 from C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\C++\GUI_Train\Libs\Window.h:5,
                 from C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\C++\GUI_Train\Libs\GUI.h:10:
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/wingdi.h:3467:28: note:                 'WINBOOL Polygon(HDC, const POINT*, int)'
 3467 |   WINGDIAPI WINBOOL WINAPI Polygon(HDC hdc,CONST POINT *apt,int cpt);
      |                            ^~~~~~~
C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\C++\GUI_Train\Libs\Test_output.cpp:9:5: error: 'poly' was not declared in this scope
    9 |     poly.add(Point{300,200}); // add a point
```

Error When Polygon is commented just to compile code without polygon:

```
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgW0oJL.o: in function `main':
C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\C++\GUI_Train\Libs/Test_output.cpp:7: undefined reference to `Simple_window::Simple_window(Graph_lib::Point, int, int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\C++\GUI_Train\Libs/Test_output.cpp:14: undefined reference to `Simple_window::wait_for_button()'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgW0oJL.o:Test_output.cp:(.rdata$_ZTV13Simple_window[_ZTV13Simple_window]+0x20): undefined reference to `Graph_lib::Window::draw()'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgW0oJL.o:Test_output.cp:(.rdata$.refptr._ZTVN9Graph_lib6ButtonE[.refptr._ZTVN9Graph_lib6ButtonE]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for Graph_lib::Button'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgW0oJL.o:Test_output.cp:(.rdata$.refptr._ZTVN9Graph_lib6WindowE[.refptr._ZTVN9Graph_lib6WindowE]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for Graph_lib::Window'
```

this is my tasks:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-lfltk",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Comment: So remove the `using namespace Graph_lib;` to avoid pulling both different `Polygon` together?

Comment: Removed it but error is the same

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors And “fancy” images are even worse.

Comment: hello sir, I thought that if there is an option to upload image I could use it, I uploaded almost all information and plus images

Comment: @BekaTchigladze It's not about using it, it's about _how_ you use it. A good use could be screenshots of buggy Renderings. Bad uses are for putting code or error messages..

Comment: OK I removed images thank you for this feedback

Comment: *"but error is the same"* Is it exactly the same? Can you update the code in question?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Updated Please see the error message when comment out `using namespace Graph_lib`

Comment: Ah, they automatically do `using namespace Graph_lib;`. Try spelling it as `Graph_lib::Polygon`.

Comment: but which files do I have to compile? just these 2? which I #included?